# $\ker f$-Which of the following is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following is true??

$$A: \ \ \ f:[a]_{8} \in \mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow [a]_{24} \in \mathbb{Z}_{24} \\ \text{ The sum of the square of the correspondents of } \ker f \text{ is } 320$$

$$B: \ \ \ f:[a]_{24} \in \mathbb{Z}_{24} \rightarrow [a]_{6} \in \mathbb{Z}_{6} \\ \text{ The sum of the square of the correspondents of } \ker f \text{ is } 504$$

$$C: \ \ \ f:[a]_{15} \in \mathbb{Z}_{15} \rightarrow [a]_{20} \in \mathbb{Z}_{20} \\ \text{ The sum of the square of the correspondents of } \ker f \text{ is } 270$$

I think that $B$ is the answer since the other $f$'s are not well-defined...

Could you tell me if it correct??

Comment: why do you think others are not well defined??

Comment: A: $$[8]_8=[0]_8$$
$$f([8]_8)=[8]_{24} \neq [0]_{24}=f([0]_8)$$

C: $$[15]_{15}=[0]_{15}$$
$$f([15]_{15})=[15]_{20} \neq [0]_{20}=f([0]_{15})$$

Is this correct??

Comment: Yes.. That is it... what can you say about the other map?

Comment: $$[a]_{24}=[b]_{24} \Rightarrow 24 \mid a-b$$
$$f([a]_{24})=[a]_6$$
$$f([b]_{24})=[b]_6$$
$$6 \mid 24 , 24 \mid a-b \Rightarrow 6 \mid a-b \Rightarrow [a]_6=[b]_6 \Rightarrow f([a]_{24})=f([b]_{24})$$
So it is well defined.
$$Kerf=\{[a]_{24}: f([a]_{24})=[0]_6 \}=\{[0], [6], [12], [18] \}$$
Is this correct??

Comment: Yes... you are right!

Comment: How can I check if the sum of the correspondents of $Kerf$ is equal to $504$?

Comment: I do not understand what does he mean by correspondents...

Comment: Is the $Kerf$ that I found correct?? I thought we could do it as followed:
$$[0+6+12+18]_{24}=[36]_{24}=[12]_{24}$$ But $[504]_{24}=[0]_{24}$... Should I do something else??

Comment: What is a correspondent?

Comment: I had written the exercise wrong...It asks the sum of the square of the correspondents/representative, the elements of the $Kerf$ (for example $[24]$ belongs also in the kern but it's "represented" by $[0]$): $$[0^2+6^2+12^2+18^2]=[504]$$